# Click a button on the row of the table and remove the row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

```
      <table id="myList">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Product ID</th>
                       <th>Product Name</th>
                       <th>Quantity</th>
                       <th>&nbsp;</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td>123</td>
                       <td>Hello</td>
                       <td>2</td>
                       <td><button>Delete</button></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

Hi,

I have a table as shown above. I want to be able to delete the specific row after click on the button delete.

May I ask how do I delete the specific selected row after clicking the delete button?

Comment: Any jQuery - or just plain vanilla javascript?

Comment: Are you using pure javascript? Or do you use jQuery or some other framework?

Comment: There are several thousand examples of doing this, both on SO and elsewhere. What specific part of it are you having trouble with? What have found in your research? Where in your attempts to use what you've found are you running into trouble?

Comment: A pen or fiddle of what you've tried would be great for us to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowIndex` to find which row need to be deleted.

Use [`deleteRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow) method to delete the row

Hope this snippet will be useful.

Here `x` will be the button

`x.parentElement` will be the `td` which contain the button

`x.parentElement.parentElement` will be the `tr` which need to be deleted

```
function delRow(x){
   document.getElementById("myList").deleteRow(x.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex);
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xu97rL7n/)